# Почему может не отрабатывать 7z.exe при высове через spawnlp или execlp?

Tags: c, 7z, c++

Всем доброго дня. Пишу программу, в коде нужно вызвать дочерний процесс 7-зипа с передачей аргументов.

Строка с вызовом:

```
spawnlp(P_WAIT, "7z", "t", "C:\\\Users\\\Administrator\\\root.war", NULL);
```

7z возвращает `incorrect command line`.

В консоли для проверки архива нужно выполнить

```
7z t C:\Users\Administrator\root.war
```

Вопрос: почему 7z возвращает `incorrect command line`, ведь аргументы передаются правильные?

Спасибо.

Comment: у вас виндовс а эта функция из опен сурц систем (posix), на сайте микрософта не рекомендуют ее использовать яб вам посоветовал использовать функцию system каторая вызывает БАТ файл в котором выполняютца инструкции по обработке

Comment: Через систем работает сейчас. С системом другая проблема. Если я запускаю сам собранный ехешник, то все сообщения cout в окне cmd отобраюаются согласно их порядку в коде. Если же запускаю ехешник с перенаправлением вывода в файл для создания лога (> или >>), то, несмотря на то, что у меня cout находится ДО система, вначале в лог пишется вывод систем, потом только сиаут. WTF понять не могу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, нужно вызывать как

```
spawnlp(P_WAIT, "7z", "7z", "t", "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\root.war", NULL);
```

Путь к программе и нулевой аргумент командной строки передаются отдельно и имеют право не совпадать. (Проверьте, что вам не нужно указывать полный путь.)

Comment: В path есть упоминание о 7з, пути не нужны. Я же говорю, мне 7з возвращает ошибку, а не cmd.

Спасибо, помогло. Вам нетрудно в 2-х словах объяснить, почему так сработало?

Comment: @Sonne: Смотрите. Первый `"7z"` есть имя/путь к файлу для исполнения. Второй `"7z"` есть `argv[0]` для программы. `"t"` есть `argv[1]` для программы и т. д.

Любая программа ищет аргументы, начиная с `argv[1]`. При вашем старом вызове, `argv[1]` было не `"t"`, а `"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\root.war"`, то есть, программе казалось, что её запустили не так:

    7z.ехе t C:\Users\Administrator\root.war

а так:

    t.ехе C:\Users\Administrator\root.war

Comment: Если я правильно понял, значит ли это, что вашей строкой открывается файл 7z.exe, в котором ищется функция 7z.exe, которой передаются параметры t, path, а в моем случае открывается файл 7z.exe, в котором вызывается функция t, которой передается параметр path? И ваша сработала, потому что в файле 7z.exe есть описание 7z.exe, а моя не сработала, потому что в файле 7z.exe нет описания t? Я параллельно читаю что такое аргв, не знание теории сказывается, как вы уже заметили...

Не злитесь на глупые вопросы, я вообще админ по профессии, но всегда хотел кодить, а в универе был только асм и labview.

Comment: @Sonne: не совсем так. Более корректно следующее описание: вы запускаете файл `7z.exe` (первое использование), и сообщаете ему, что он запущен как `7z.exe` (второе использование) с параметрами `t` и `C:\Users\Administrator\root.war`. Обычно программе пофиг, под каким именем её запустили, поэтому

    spawnlp(P_WAIT, "7z", "превед кросавчег", "t", "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\root.war", NULL);

скорее всего тоже бы сработало. Можно в первом приближении считать, что аргумент 3 просто игнорируется.

Comment: Опередили на минуту) как раз хотел спросить а сработало бы оно с аргв "" :) 
А значение аргв0 на практике вообще зачем-нибудь используется (если не в винде, то в posix-системах) или оно формальность?

Comment: @Sonne: По юникс-системами — да, используется. Например, `vi` может быть symlink с `vim`, программа при старте смотрит на argv[0] и в зависимости от этого ведёт себя либо как `vi`, либо как `vim`.

Comment: Значит, заморочка с posix'ом. И винда адекватно воспримент аргв0 только в сигвине, получается...
Спасибо большое!

А есть мысли, почему логируется криво? И со спауном тоже криво.

Comment: @Sonne: Пожалуйста!

---
По поводу логирования: возможно, проблема в flush'е? При выводе на консоль flush происходит при каждом `\n`, а в файл буферизируется большими кусками. (Как поправить — не знаю, например, может быть, flush'ить cout вручную?)